# can i use twilio with simple rest url

Tags: rest, twilio

when I call this
it just seems to return my last few messages that i sent using the helper page

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC6dcac367bc95962fceb45ce391dbc712/Messages.json&From=+44mynum&To=+44mynum&body=test&id=-myid-&token=-mytoken-

no error and doesn;t send the message ?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You need to make a POST request to that, with your message on the body.

You seem to only be making a GET request, thus only asking Twilio for messages. The parameters you're passing are being ignored as Twilio doesn't know how to handle them in a GET request.

Try using something like Postman, or anything similar that allows you to make that request as a POST,  and it will work.

Let me know otherwise, and I'll help you debugging it.

Comment: I have put this in a post and now I just get credentials not recognised. giving up.